# How to insert UTF-8 character into Text datatype into SQL Server using EF?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, utf-8

I want insert utf-8 char into SQL Server but if data type text output ??????????????????????, work for all data type but not work in text data type

Table structure:

[image]

C# code:

```
news.System_Date = DateTime.Now;
            news.Staff = Base_Tables.Current_User.ID;
            db.News.Add(news);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

> if not use EF set N char work but i don't know in EF

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: .NET uses *Unicode* for strings. If you see `????` it means you tried to load *non-*Unicode text using the wrong codepage. Either your table fields are *not* `ntext` or `nvarchar` or you loaded text from a non-Unicode file using the wrong codepage. The text was garbled before it was even assigned to the class properties

Comment: The `text` type has been deprecated for *well over a decade*. Marc links to the current documentation but it's been saying the same since 2005. It's well over time that it should be replaced.

Comment: How and where do you read that text from, and how do you store it in the database? Where do `title` and `subtitle` come from? Please post your code.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Open your `edmx` file, select the entity column that is mapped to the `NVARCHAR` column with the problem and go to it's properties.

Set the `Unicode` property to `True`.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Then make sure that you are assigning the value correctly when generating the row on C# and also using a decent client that can handle unicode to see the data from the database (the row might be stored correctly and the client might not be able to display it with the proper encoding).

Comment: this is true but not worl

Answer (score 1):

`text` is a "single byte per character" data type that does not understand Unicode - as you found out. You need to use `nvarchar(max)` instead, like you used for Title and Subtitle.

- The "n" prefix means that it *does* understand Unicode.
- And use `nvarchar(max)` (or maybe `varchar(max)` if you don't want Unicode) instead of `text` as text is deprecated