# Error when saving the Bodytext of an email in SQL

Tags: vba, string, outlook

In VBA for outlook some emails trigger an error when I try to save (part of) the bodytext to a SQL table.
The error occurrs as soon as I set the fieldvalue to part of the bodytext (e.g. to left(MailItem.Body, 500) as the field is only 500 characters long). That is: it occurrs before the line that updates the table!
I'd provide sample code to reproduce the problem, but the point is that only some mails, very few in fact, give the error  and I wouldn't know how to send an 'Outlook.EmailItem' to this forum. Therefore, I'm just asking in a general way: does anyone recognize this problem?
It seems like a strange kind of string that produces this error. I won't dwell on my amateuristic investigations; I ended up making a function which 'rebuilds' the string from 'MailItem.Body' using the ascii values of the characters. I now use it whenever the error occurrs and that works just fine. (I only use the first 500 characters, by the way.)

```
Function BuildNewString(strInput As String)
Dim strOUT As String
Dim pos1 As Long
    For pos1 = 1 To Len(strInput)
        strOUT = strOUT & Chr$(Asc(Mid$(strInput, pos1, 1)))
    Next
    BuildNewString = strOUT
End Function
```

But I do not know why I need this function and that's upsetting.
So here is my question in a more general form: has anyone ever encountered, in VBA, an occasion where two strings were different when using a comparison of strings, but identical when comparing them on the asciii values of their characters?
Is this maybe a well-known phenomenon? I am very much an amateur; please forgive my ignorance.

Just in case someone is as stumped as I am and would like to try on their own mailfolders I'll provide the code I used to analyse the problem. In my folders, it triggered messages in about 5% of the mails and it was always either character 63 or sometimes 32. It made no difference whether I took MailItem.Body or MailItem.HTMLBody (except for the position of the anomaly of course).

```
Sub ScanBodytext()
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strBody As String
    Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNS.PickFolder
    For Each olMail In olFolder.Items
        strBody = Left(olMail.Body, 1000)
        If DetectAnomaly(strBody) Then
            MsgBox "difference in mail d.d. " & olMail.ReceivedTime & vbCrLf & "from: " & olMail.SenderEmailAddress & vbCrLf & "subject: " & olMail.Subject
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "All mails in folder were scanned."
End Sub

Function DetectAnomaly(strInput As String) As Boolean
Dim pos1 As Long
Dim strChar As String
Dim intCharVal As Integer
    For pos1 = 1 To Len(strInput)
        strChar = Mid$(strInput, pos1, 1)
        intCharVal = Asc(strChar)
        If strChar <> Chr(intCharVal) Then
            MsgBox "anomaly at " & CStr(pos1) & ", char: '" & strChar & ", ascii: " & CStr(intCharVal)
            DetectAnomaly = True
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

I'm not quite sure whether all of the 'anomalous' strings trigger an error when I try to save to sql, but fact is that the 'BuildNewString' function given above solves all problems so the 'anomalies' must have something to do with it, I'd say.
I'd be so grateful for any kind of explanation,
Hans

Comment: The "anomaly" happens when you have characters that are not within 0..255. `Asc` handles only 1 byte characters. Passing a 2 byte character will let `Asc` return a wrong value. You can use AscW to get the code of 2 byte characters. You failed to describe the error itself you get, but if your database field can hold only 500 bytes (not 500 characters), having such a 2 byte character within your string will let the field overflow.

Comment: Might help to give us the field definition from the database you're using, and tell us what database platform you have.  From your previous question it seems to be SQL server?  `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mailarchive]( [EmailID] [decimal](19, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, [AuthorAddress] varchar NULL, [sampletext] varchar NULL) ON [PRIMARY]` and `sampletext` is the relevant field?

Comment: Maybe update your table to this:  `[sampletext] nvarchar NULL` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54475073/how-to-insert-utf-8-character-into-text-datatype-into-sql-server-using-ef

Comment: The 'anomalies'were off course due to 2-byte characters. Sorry for my ignorance; I'd maybe expect them in MailItem.HTMLbody but not in MailItem.Body.
As for my problem with SQL: changing the definition of the field (sampletext) from varchar to nvarchar seems to do the trick. I gather from the documentation that in later versions of SQL-server (2019) a 'varchar' filed also stores Unicode characters.
Thanks a lot for pointing me to the function AscW, by the way!